# CAN'T Build Apache spark with MAVEN

Tags: java, apache, maven

I have downloaded Apache spark and trying to build it with MAVEN as suggested here. http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/building-with-maven.html

But I am not able to resolve the error after running the command -
  **build/mvn -DskipTests clean package run** , the error is- **build/mvn: No such file or directory .** 
I checked by running **mvn -v** and also **JAVA_HOME** is set to the JDK.**(screen shot attached )** .
Please  help to resolve the problem.[command promt output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFlhz.png)

Comment: Just run `mvn -DskipTests clean package run`.

Comment: Thanks ! it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mvn -DskipTests clean package run
```

You don't need to use build/mvn. I am assuming you have mvn installed somewhere within the system.